# Can a TypeScript type implement an interface?

Tags: typescript, interface

I'm learning TypeScript and I want to extend a `type` with an `interface`, [I've found a blog post](https://blog.bitsrc.io/type-vs-interface-in-typescript-cf3c00bc04ae) which suggests that it's not possible for a `type` to extend/implement `interfaces`.

Here is a code example of what I would like to do:

```typescript
interface IPet {
    needsFood: boolean
}

// How I would like to use the IPet interface with a type, 
type Cat implements IPet = {
    needsFood: boolean,
    color: string,
}
```

The above code exampel gives an error. `'IPet' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

Here is how I would use the IPet interface with a `Class`, but is it possible to have the same behavior with a `type`

```typescript
class Cat implements IPet {
    needsFood: boolean;
    color: string
}
```

Is there any way I can have a `type` implementing an interface? Or do I need to use a `Class` if I want to use interfaces?

---

**Edit:** Thanks for all the comments guys, I have updated the question with a code example. What I'm really looking for here is basically just a yes/no answer whether it's possible to have a TypeScript type extend/implement an interface.

Comment: You could use an intersection type if that's what you're looking for. [Example Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIImAWzgG2QbwF8AoMATwAcUARAewHNkBeNDbPAMgOOWQCM4UANYAKAJQAuZADdawACYBuYoWVA)

Comment: Types can't *implement* an interface (or anything else), only runtime code can do that. They can *extend* an interface. You do that either with `interface X extends TheInterface` or, as @Behemoth said, via intersection: `type X = /*...something...*/ & TheInterface;`.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that shows what you've tried.  Otherwise this question will likely be closed as lacking details.

Comment: But `Cat` doesn't implement `IPet`.  Do you mean `extends`?  You can't do that with `type` aliases directly either, but it's a different question. ... if you did that with a `class` you'd get an error because `needsFood` is missing.

Comment: You can't use an `implements` or an `extends` clause but you can do other things that are mostly equivalent: [see this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mxzA8w). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, that answers the question, include the part that you can't actually use an `implements` or `extends` clause. Thanks.

Comment: Okay I'll write an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question as asked is no, you cannot do this directly with [a `type` alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases).  An [`implements` clause](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#implements-clauses) only applies to `class` declarations, and an [`extends` clause](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#extending-types) only applies to `interface` or `class` declarations.

Of course it is easy enough to get analogous functionality:

---

An `implements` clause on a class just checks to see if the class instance is assignable to the declared type, and produces a compiler warning if it's not; it has no effect on the type of
the instance.  You can do the same thing with a utility type like

```
type Implements<T, U extends T> = U
```

So `Implements<T, U>` doesn't have an effect on the resulting type, `U`, but since `U` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `T`, you will get a warning if it is not assignable.

Let's test it:

```
type Cat = Implements<IPet, {
    needsFood: boolean,
    color: string,
}> // okay

type Dog = Implements<IPet, {
    bark(): void 
}>; // error!  Property 'needsFood' is missing in type '{ bark(): void; }'
```

Looks good.

---

Meanwhile an `extends` clause can be used to add members to or narrow members of a parent type.  This is essentially the same as an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types), and so we can make a utility type to capture this:

```
type Extends<T, U extends Pick<T, keyof T & keyof U>> =
    T & U;
```

Here we combine both the parent type `T` and the new members `U`.  I've constrained `U` to make sure that you can't add conflicting properties, which is similar to what happens if you try to extend an interface with conflicting properties:

```
type Cat2 = Extends<IPet, {
    color: string
}>

type Dog2 = Extends<IPet, {
    needsFood: number // error! 
}>; // error! 
// Type '{ needsFood: number; }' does not satisfy the constraint Pick<IPet, "needsFood">.
```

Also looks good.

---

Those approaches aren't completely identical to `implements`/`extends` clauses, but they should be close enough for a lot of use cases.  There are almost surely edge cases where they differ and it's possible these could be repaired or worked around.  But the basic takeaway here is that you can use generic constraints and intersection types to build a solution.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Answer (score 0):

In TypeScript, you can indeed extend a type with an interface. The syntax for extending a type with an interface is using the extends keyword. Here's an example:

```js
interface Shape {
  color: string;
}

type Square = Shape & {
  sideLength: number;
}

let square: Square = {
  color: "blue",
  sideLength: 10
};
```

This creates a new type Square that extends the Shape interface with an additional property sideLength. You can also use interfaces with classes for defining the shape of the instances of the class. Classes in TypeScript can implement interfaces to enforce that the class meets the structure defined by the interface.

So, you can use both types and classes to work with interfaces in TypeScript.